# Using a batch file for Depicus WOL

Tags: command-line, batch, wake-on-lan

I am very new to coding and i am currently being tasked with making a WOL script to wake up multiple machines at once.
Some WOL softwares have a command line feature, like this one: http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd.aspx which help allot. I can make 1 machine wake up just fine, however i need it to wake up many machines. My plan is to make a batch file to run with the CMD WOL.

This is where the issue comes in, i am absolutely clueless about how to do this, i have looked on google how to make this batch file but found no good guides.

Here is my question to you, Could you give me advice/tips on how to make this batch file please.

Many thanks

Steven

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Open command prompt and Go to the directory where this command line tool is present.
Issue the following command.
\path\wolcmd [mac address] [ipaddress] [subnet mask] [port number]

Batch file example (wakenow.bat):
\path\wolcmd.exe 0007E90E7A66 10.10.10.10 255.0.0.0 9
\path\wolcmd.exe 50E549467AAD 10.10.10.11 255.0.0.0 9


This is what i got right now. Its an example, let me know if i need any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a .bat or .cmd file and add a line for each machine

```
wolcmd AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 192.168.43.255 255.255.255.0 4343
wolcmd BB:BB:CC:DD:EE:AA 192.168.43.255 255.255.255.0 4343
```